# Overhead of creating lambda for multiple threads in c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, lambda

I have a `concurrency::parallel_for` inside which I call a function taking a functor, passing it a lambda, like

```
concurrency::parallel_for(0, particleCount, [&](int i)
{
...
  kdTree->VisitCells([&](const KDTreeNode &node) //defining and passing
  {
   //code dealing with tree traversal
  }
}
```

...and the question is if it is bad practice to define the lambda inside the `parallel_for`, which is run for each of a lot of particles. Will this essentially define one functor for every particle?
The alternative is to write the lambda outside the `parallel_for` and design it to take a few more arguments (since it can then no longer do the same captures as before) and pass that to the tree inside the `parallel_for`.

When testing this, it seems it is ever so slightly faster defining it outside the `parallel_for`, but the data is inconclusive, and I am not certain exactly how multiple identical lambdas with different captured data is really handled.

Comment: I think it would be more fruitful to just capture the variables you need for the lambda instead of capturing the whole context. And of course measure thoroughly before making any conclusions about performance. I'd say lambda object creation would be negligible compared to the rest of the code performed in the loop.

Comment: if performance testing is inconclusive, do the thing that's easy to maintain. If your game-players start moaning about lag in the particle animations, then is the time to think about optimisation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, it depends on two things.

Firstly, unless the definition "outside" `parallel_for` is essentially a class or struct that somehow captures references to all variables within `parallel_for`, you are comparing apples with oranges.   The capture spec `[&]` essentially makes the lambda notation a shorthand for creating such a structure.   If you were to use a different capture specification, you would essentially change the nature of the struct/class being created (or make it a function if nothing is captured) and therefore change the overhead of creating and using it.

Second, assuming you are actually comparing apples with apples, any difference will come down to quality of implementation of the compiler, how memory is allocated by the program and things like that.

With a high quality compiler, I'd be inclined to bet the compiler will do a better job with the lambda capture than you would do by rolling an equivalent data structure by hand (hence I suspect that you are not comparing like with like).

Assuming you are using a decent quality compiler (you haven't specified) I would therefore bet that the nebulous advantage you are seeing "defining it outside the the `parallel_for`" is because you are comparing a hand-rolled simple function or struct definition with a lambda that is capturing several variables (forcing the compiler to pack up a larger data structure).   In other words, you are comparing an apple with an orange.

With a lower quality compiler .... well, it just depends.  You can bet any way you like.